# Drupal 7 is unable to install modules

Tags: php, drupal, iis-7, zend-server-ce

My instance of Drupal 7 is unable to install new modules via FTP link. The error message that comes up is as follows :

```
Warning: fileowner() [function.fileowner]: stat failed for temporary://upd92FE.tmp in update_manager_local_transfers_allowed() (line 924 of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\drupal\modules\update\update.manager.inc).
```

My setup is as follows :

Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit
IIS 7.5 + Zend Community Server

Comment: Your question is to make it work? It actually reads more like you should file a bug report with Drupal. Though the cause is probably your non-standard setup (Windows and no Apache).

Comment: I see, I figured it should work on IIS since it was on the IIS platform installer. Sigh...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, found the solution.

For some odd reason the temp directory was set as the following:
[image]

This naturally would not work. Just alter the back slash to a forward slash and you will be all set =)

Comment: This helped me solve the same problem (I've updated from one version of XAMPP to another, and I guess this somehow happened in the process). Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

To solve this problem, just create new folder named `tmp` in `sites/default/files`

Answer (score 0):

Navigate here as admin
/admin/config/media/file-system

and update "tmp" in Temporary Directory
And create tmp folder in root of project dir. parallel with your index.php and .htaccess

Thanks, Aj

Answer (score 0):

Sometime is a simple permission setting, I my case I found that the tmp was with 755 instead of 775. Setting back that folder to 775 has solved my problem.